# jqGrid Row Object in onSelectRow

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do I get row object on row selected in jqGrid? I need the actual object, not the cellvalue. I have gone through the documentation but could not find a method that will give me the row object. since I use custom formatters, the cellValue will not work.

Answer (score 11):

If you implement [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) and want to get the cell value with respect of [getCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) or [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) you have to implement [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) function also.

It is not clear what you mean under "I need the actual object, not the cellvalue". It is also unclear which `datatype` you use, whether you use `loadonce: true` option or not and if you load the data from the server in which format the data will be posted to the server.

If you use `datatype: 'local'` or use `loadonce: true` the internal `data` and `_index` parameters will be filled. To get raw data from the grid by `rowid` you can use

```
var rowData = this.p.data[this.p._index[rowid]]
```

or

```
var grid = $(this),
    localdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    indexes = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index'),
    rowData = localdata[indexes[rowid]];
```

If you don't use `datatype: 'local'` or use `loadonce: true` and load the data from the server only you can save the object represented the data from the server response in a variable (in an object). The `loadComplete` event handler has one `data` parameter which is the raw data posted from the server. So you are able to save the data which you need in a object (in a map which will get yut object by rowid) and use it inside of the `onSelectRow` event handler.

Comment: @SystemParadox: You are welcome! I recommend you additionally examine the `getLocalRow` method. Look [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145342/315935) or [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10362294/315935) for some small code examples and additional information. [The source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L3494-3505) of the method is very small and I recommend you to read it too.

Comment: I have to admit, I always overlooked it, but the storing the data for later use on the loadComplete is a very valuable functionality. Since I never use   datatype : 'local' or loadonce : true. I even wonder why it isn't stored by default in some kind of 'rawdata' property. Anyway thanks for pointing it out Oleg. +1

Comment: @Steven: You are welcome! I recommend to use `loadonce: true` and small `rowNum` (the page size) in case if the total number of rows less as 1000 or even 10000. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) uses 4000 rows, 13 columns and 20 rows in a page and [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) display 40000 rows. You can try to sort, page and filter the grid to see the performance.

Comment: @Oleg : Hi Oleg thanks for the great examples. I'm aware that loading all data at once has only benefits. Unforunately loading data from db (which is beyond my responsibility) takes in many cases too long to load if I request all data. So I send paged queries to the db too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the getInd and getLocalRow methods:

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid) {
    var row = $(this).getLocalRow(rowid);
    // do something with row
}
```

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Answer (score 3):

in my project:

```
ondblClickRow : function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
    $($("#completeDetail").getInd(rowid,true)).find(":first").click();
}
```

This would solve the row increase not find looking for the row

use this function -> `getInd(rowid,rowcontent)`.

This method returns the index of the row in the grid table specified by `id=rowid` when rowcontent set to false (default). If rowcontent is set to true, it returns the entry row object. If the rowid can not be found, the function returns false.