# How to update value of data in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to update a cell in jqgrid permanently upon loading.  I know I can use `setCell` but that only updates the value for that page.  If I come back to the page if I don't explicit perform another `setCell` for the cell the old value is shown.  I've also tried setRowData but it appears to be doing the same thing.  I'm using the `loadonce` as my approach is to 1) load the data 2) modify a few values of the data based on some criteria 3) show the modified values.  As I'm using `loadonce` shouldn't there be a way to modify a cell permanently in this session?

UPDATE:

Putting in my code that isn't giving an error but failing to iterate through all data:

```
var set = 0;

....

gridComplete: function(data){
    setData();
},

....

beforeRefresh: function(data){
    set = 0;
},

....

function setData(){

if(set == 1) return;
... //create hash up here
  var dataArray = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
  var j = 1;
  for (var rows in dataArray) {
    var key = dataArray[rows].name;
    dataArray[rows].level = hashTable[key];
    j++;
  }
  alert(j);
}
```

This is not cycling through all items in the array that are locally loaded.  For example, if page size is set to 30, the `alert(j)` returns 30, despite how many items I have locally loaded.  However, if I refresh the graph the j is the correct number.  Why is the behavior of getGridParam different in each case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you use `loadonce: true` you should know **where** the local data will be hold by jqGrid. jqGrid has two options: `data` and `_index`. The `data` is array of items where every item has the name property as the `name` property of the columns from `colModel`. If you need find the item by id (rowid) you can use `_index[rowid]` to the the item with the rowid in the `data` array. So to change the data in the column `'myColumn'` you should do the following:

```
// first change the cell in the visible part of grid
myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'myColumn', newValue);

// now change the internal local data
var dataArray = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    indexes = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
dataArray[indexes[rowid]].myColumn = newValue;
```

**UPDATED**: You can use documented [getLocalRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to change the local data:

```
// first change the cell in the visible part of grid
myGrid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'myColumn', newValue);

// now change the internal local data
myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).myColumn = newValue;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand this.  How do I do a 'dataArray[indexes[rowid]].myColumn'?  would the exact code for a column called personName be:   dataArray[indexes[rowid]].'personName'  ?  Because that caused an error.  Also, why do I have to also call setCell?  If I am really modifying the data array, won't future renderings of the data show the new values?

Comment: Also, in your code you say to call 'setCell', then modify the data array.  The data array should be much larger than just the cells that setCell will work with, correct?  I should no longer need to call setCell each time I cycle through pages, sort or filter, correct?

Comment: @WildBill: The `dataArray[indexes[rowid]].personName` or `dataArray[indexes[rowid]]['personName']` will change only the *internal* jqGrid data, but not the contain of the `<td>` element of the grid. You can modify the internal data and call `trigger('reloadGrid')`, but the usage of `setCell` is better as full reloading of the grid.

Comment: I'm really confused about what myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index'); is doing.  index is an object, correct?  Shouldn't there be "getGridParams('records') number of elements in dataArray?  When I try to iterate through those elements I keep getting an error.  Plus I don't see _index as an option for getGridParam.  Is there any documentation on it anywhere?

Comment: @WildBill: The `_index` are used starting with jqGrid 3.7 (starting with existing the local data). You can use [getLocalRow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L3425-3436) to get the local data but there are currently no `setLocalRow` which you need. If you post the code how you iterate through the elements I could see the error. To iterate `_index` you should use `for (var i in _index)` and the `data` is the standard array.

Comment: @WildBill: You can use `myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).personName = 'newValue'` to change the value with respect of the method.

Comment: Updated code above to show where issues reside.  Looks like getGridParam is either weird or I don't understand something fundamental about jqGrid.....

Comment: @WildBill: Sorry, but I don't understand what you what to do in the code which you posted. What is `hashTable`? Why you don't use `_index`? The index is object and you can enumerate it's properties with `for (var rowid in indexes)`. The `dataArray` is array. You should not use `for (var rows in dataArray)`. It will be OK for C#, but not good for JavaScript. You should not use reserved name `set` as variable. The code which you posed changes `level` property in `data`, but changes nothing in the displayed grid. What you really want to do?

Comment: I'm actually working in jquery and not C#.  I omitted the changing of the text in the visual grid but I know how to do that.  What I am trying to do is 1) load data from server and then 2) modify it based on some other rule on the client side.  I tried to iterate through the dataarray but it does not appear that jqgrid allows one to do so.  Hastable is a hash that I define through a few functions.  It figures out what the data should be modified to after looking at all of the data.  So what remains is "How do I modify the entire array on the client side for the duration of the session?"

Comment: Also I still don't understand how to use index.  Is it documented anywhere on the Internet?  Where does rowid come from in this statement:  dataArray[indexes[rowid]].myColumn = newValue;

Comment: Ahhh, I got it....  I found a way not to use _index but the dataarry was the key to thesolution.  I was creating my hash with getCell, so the approach you suggested is correct.

Comment: @WildBill: I am glad to read that your code works now. Nevertheless I am not sure that everything is correct. If you fill `hashTable` using `getCell` then it can contains only information about *visible* rows. To enumerate *all* rows returned from the server you should first get `indexes` with `var indexes = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');` then enumerate *all* rowids with `for (var rowid in indexes) { var item = dataArray[indexes[rowid]]; ...}` In the way you will get `item` which represent every row. Currently the `_index` in not documented.

Comment: Yes you are correct.   I think I failed to articulate the issue but yes, using getCell was what was giving me an incomplete hashTable...

Comment: @Oelg you should write a book or something on jqGrid; like a jqGrid Ninja or jqGrid - The road less traveled!

Comment: @VivekRagunathan: Thanks! I think about the book, but still don't found enough the time for writing.

Comment: This is THE way to go when updating rows in jqGrid

Comment: @Oleg you are a wizard. Can't thank you enough

Answer (score 0):

For all who came here from google, here is an updated answer!

important is the index, which you can get by calling getInd-Method. Because rowID != index of localRowData. (eq. rowId: jqg204, Index: 5)

**EDIT:** if set "key : true" in colmodel you can set your own rowId (diffrent from my example "jqg###", usually a PK from a database table)

```
var ind = myGrid.getInd(rowId);
var localRowData  = myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', ind);
localRowData.myColumn = newValue;
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:
I needed to update a row upon a certain user-action (irrelevant).
For that, I needed to know the exact row from the 'data' object, even after some filtering of the table.
So I found a way to identify which row was changed - I added a RowID property for each item of the 'data' object, at the 'loadComplete' event:

```js
loadComplete: function () {
            if (firstRun) {
                firstRun = false;
                var dataArray = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
                $(dataArray).each(function (index) {
                    dataArray[index].RowID = index + 1;
                });
            }
        }
```

And now, at the formatter code, I was able to access rData.RowID to identify the exact row on which the action was taken, and to get/set its 'data' representation