# Updating value in jqGrid doesn't work when two columns use same field

Tags: jqgrid

I used the solution mentioned in [How to update value of data in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145163/how-to-update-value-of-data-in-jqgrid) to update data locally. It worked for me as shown in the first fiddle. In the "Action" column, there is button added conditionally, based on the data in "IsActive" column. If it is "true", a "Retire" button gets added as an action. If it is false, "Activate" button gets added. When the javascript function is called, the button changes to "Activate".

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/rqab1veh/10/)

Now, I added another column to display the status value as text. Now, both "Status" column and "Action" column are utilizing the same data column - IsActive. After adding this column, the javascript function is not changing the button from "Retire" to "Activate".

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/rqab1veh/11/)

What is the best way to fix this issue?

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function updateActiveStatus(rowid, isToActive) {

alert('function');

                        // first change the cell in the visible part of grid
                        $("#list").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'firstname', 'A');

                        // now change the internal local data
                        $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).firstname = 'A';


                        $("#list").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'IsActive', false);
                        $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid).IsActive = false;



            }


            var myData = [

                { "id": "35", "firstname": null, "codeval": "G", "note": "xx7866", "amount": "23", "IsActive": true },
                { "id": "73", "firstname": null, "codeval": "W", "note": "dd1047", "amount": "34", "IsActive": true },
                { "id": "75", "firstname": "LORA", "codeval": "H", "note": "rr7323", "amount": "56", "IsActive": true },
                { "id": "95", "firstname": "EST", "codeval": "M", "note": "gg574", "amount": "55", "IsActive": true }
                ],

                myGrid = $("#list");

            myGrid.jqGrid({
                datatype:'local',
                data: myData,
                colNames: ['ID', 'FirstName', 'Code', 'Amount', 'Note', 'Action'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int'},
                    {name:'firstname',width:80, align:'center'},
                    { name: 'codeval',  width: 70 },
                    {name:'amount',width:100, formatter:'number'},
                    {name:'note',index:'note',width:100,sortable:false},
                     {
                        name: 'IsActive',
                        width: 100,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)                                                 {
                            if (cellvalue == true) {
                                return '<div style="padding-left:5px;"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default app-custom-button-retire" >' +
                                        '<span title="" class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-scissors"></span>Retire' +
                                        '</button></div>';
                            }
                            else {
                                return '<div style="padding-left:5px;"><button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default app-custom-button-activate" >' +
                                        '<span title="" class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>Activate' +
                                        '</button></div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                rowNum:10,
                pager: '#pager',
                gridview:true,
                ignoreCase:true,
                rownumbers:true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                height: '100%',
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
                        rowid = $td.parent().attr("id"),
                        //rowData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
                        rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid)
                    iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
                    colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

                    celValue = $self.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'FirstName');

                    if (iCol >= 0 && colModel[iCol].name === "IsActive") {

                        if ($(e.target).hasClass("app-custom-button-retire")) {
                            updateActiveStatus(rowid,false);
                            return false;
                        }

                        if ($(e.target).hasClass("app-custom-button-activate")) {

                            updateActiveStatus(rowid, true);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }


                    //Avoid selection of row
                    return false;
                }
            });
            myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem multiple misunderstanding in your code. First of all you have some source data, which are the array of item. Every item is object with multiple properties, like:

```js
{ "id": "75", "firstname": "LORA", "codeval": "H", "note": "rr7323",
  "amount": "56", "IsActive": true }
```

or, which is the same,

```js
{ id: "75", firstname: "LORA", codeval: "H", note: "rr7323",
  amount: "56", IsActive: true }
```

It should be clear that such item can't have **multiple properties with the same name**. The object

```js
{ "id": "75", "firstname": "LORA", "codeval": "H", "note": "rr7323",
  "amount": "56", "IsActive": true, "IsActive": true }
```

would be wrong even if some web browser could ignore the error. Even if you specify *the same* value `true` for both "IsActive" properties.

In the same way you can't use `colModel` with multiple columns with the same `name` property. Your second demo https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/rqab1veh/11/ have **two columns** with the same property `name: 'IsActive'`. It's wrong. You can fix the code by usage, for example, `name: 'IsActive1'` in the second column. The formatter of `IsActive1` can use `rowObject.IsActive` instead of `cellvalue` to access to the required data. The corresponding code will be the follwing

```js
{
    name: 'IsActive1',
    width: 75,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return rowObject.IsActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Retired';
    }
},
{
    name: 'IsActive',
    width: 100,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return cellvalue == true ? retireButton : activeButton;
    }
}
```

where `retireButton` and `activeButton` contains HTML fragments of the buttons.

Now it's important to understand, that jqGrid hold the `data` array. The method `$("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid)` get you **the reference** to the data item which corresponds the data of the row. The method `getRowData` will get the data from HTML representation of the cells (from `<td>` elements) and unformat there. The type of the fields of returned object will be strings.

Because you need to update not only the data, but the cell content of      `firstname`, `IsActive1` and `IsActive` columns then you have to call `setCell` on every the field or better call one `setRowData`:

```js
function updateActiveStatus (rowid, isToActive) {
    alert('calling the function');
    $("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, {
        firstname: 'A',
        IsActive1: false,
        IsActive: false
    });
    var item = $("#list").jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid);
    // delete unneeded IsActive1 property created in the item
    delete item.IsActive1;
}
```

The only small disadvantage of the `setRowData` call is creating new property `IsActive1` in the item of data. Old jqGrid 4.6 have no possibility to save the data "virtually" in some another place as the `item.IsActive1`. Free jqGrid allows to specify `saveLocally` callback, which can make custom "saving" of the data of the column in the local item. It's not real large problem in your case and you need just delete unneeded property by `delete item.IsActive1`

You can see the results on the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rqab1veh/12/